# SQL DATEADD Function for 7 days after the end of the last quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL Server: I'm trying to get 7 days after the end of the last quarter...

Here's what I have so far.

```
DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(q, 1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))))) AS LastDayOfLastFullQuarter
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original expression was close (you needed to add 7 days, not 0):

```
------------------v
SELECT DATEADD(D, 7, DATEDIFF(D, 0, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(q, 1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))))) AS SevenDaysAfterLastDayOfLastFullQuarter
```

But, good gravy, that's hard to read, and not just because of all the shorthand. Generally, it is better to find the beginning of the next period than the end of the current one. Subtracting a second from the beginning of this quarter won't always get you a date/time value in the previous quarter because *some types round up*.

Why not think about it as calculating 6 days after the beginning of the current quarter?

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 6, 
   DATEFROMPARTS
   (
     YEAR(@d), 
     MONTH(@d)-((MONTH(@d)-1)%3),
     1
   )
);
```

Another way that is more like Steve's, if you don't like all the math:

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEADD(QUARTER,DATEDIFF(QUARTER,'20000101',GETDATE()),'20000101');

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 6, @d);
```

I talk about both of these approaches here, and unfortunately the beginning of a quarter is not a calculation that's easy to write in a self-documenting way in T-SQL, so you get to choose between unintuitive methods (dateadd/datediff from some irrelevant date, or modulo and other math), and it gets more complicated if your fiscal calendar does not align with your cute dogs of 2020 calendar:

- [Simplify Date Period Calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

But having thought on it a moment, this approach is only a few more characters but is a little more self-documenting without the modulo and other calculations:

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 6, 
   DATEFROMPARTS
   (
     YEAR(@d), 
       CASE WHEN MONTH(@d) < 4  THEN 1 -- if Jan-Mar, want Jan
            WHEN MONTH(@d) < 7  THEN 4 -- if Apr-Jun, want Jun
            WHEN MONTH(@d) < 10 THEN 7 -- if Jul-Sep, want Jul
            ELSE 10                    -- if Oct-Dec, want Oct
       END,
     1
   )
);
```

I talk about why you should spell out date-related values (e.g. don't use `q` and `d` and `s` and `0`, though the last one is still a bad habit of mine) here:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [Date Shorthand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9321/sql-server-date-time-shorthand-and-other-tricks/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

And why you should always think about the beginnings instead of the ends of periods here:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Do Not Use BETWEEN with Dates](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9316/sql-server-between-dates-issue/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
select dateadd(month,
               -2,
               datefromparts(year(getdate()), ((month(getdate()) + 2) / 3) * 3, 7)
              )
```

Comment: super close, except its -1 month off

Answer (score 0):

This should do it too

```
select cast(dateadd(d, 7, dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), -1)) as date);
```

Results

```
2020-07-07
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date datetime = getdate();

select DATEADD(d, 6, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date), (MONTH(@date) - 1) / 3 * 3 + 1 , 1))
```